# How to change the picture size in a file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a rmarkdown file that looks like this:

```
--- 
title: "Playerreport"
output: 
 html_document:
  theme: null
  highlight: null
  css: styles.css
---
```

Now I would like to include a picture in the file. So like this:

```
  <div class="container">![Caption for the picture.](C:\Users\Frits\Pictures\zlatan.jpg)    </div>
```

And would like to style this using the following code in the .css file "styles.css"

```
.container {
width: 100px;
height: 120px;
}
```

But the picture does not change. Any thoughts what goes wrong? Other elements in .css file do work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be changing the width and height of the div and not the img. The css should be something like this:

```
.container img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

for this html:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="image.png">
</div>
```

to keep the image proportion:

```
.container img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a native pandoc-markdown solution. Since [pandoc 1.16](http://pandoc.org/releases.html#pandoc-1.16-02-jan-2016), you can use the [`link_attribute`](http://pandoc.org/README.html#images) extension either to set up an individual image size or to give it a class.

In your case, you could do this for a single image (the upside is it should work for every output format):

```
![Caption for the picture.](/path/to/pic/zlatan.jpg){width=100px height=120px}
```

And if you have to set up multiple images this way, this should work with your original css code (will only work for html output):

```
![Caption for the picture.](/path/to/pic/zlatan.jpg){.container}
```